# Can't get tree branches perpendicular to trunk with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, vector

I am using geometry nodes to build this tree. The problem is that the tree branches sprout vertical and parallel to the trunk.
[image]

These are the random points that I have on the trunk via geometry nodes. I need the branches to grow perpendicular to these points.
[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this:

[image]

i just took an icosphere and some cylinders to show as an example. If you want help with your blend file, please provide it. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is so clean. Yesterday I've done something similar but I had to use the Align Euler node.

Comment: But, I aligned instances to faces, so I think I'd still need the Align Euler node then.